# Auto prefixing joined table columns

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js

I'm looking for easier way to get two rows associated with each other.

This is a bit crazy, looking if there's any alternatives.

I'm using `knex`.

```
  async function main ({knex, table, token}) {
    let res = await knex(`${table} AS t1`)
      .select(
        't1.every as t1.every',
        't1.dog as t1.dog',
        't1.has as t1.has',
        't1.its as t1.its',
        't1.day as t1.day',
        't2.every as t2.every',
        't2.dog as t2.dog',
        't2.has as t2.has',
        't2.its as t2.its',
        't2.day as t2.day',
      )
      .where('t1.every', token)
      .innerJoin(`${table} AS t2`, 't1.day', 't2.id')
      let flat = res[0]
    let result = {}
    each(flat, (value, key) => {
      set(result, key, value)
    })
    return {
      main: result.t2,
      associated: result.t1
    }
  }
```

Comment: use normal `join` and then use library like `https://www.npmjs.com/package/treeize`